# Data Factory copy activity and ZipDeflate throughput low

Tags: ftp, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I currently have a pipeline comprised of a simple Copy activity which fetches zipped files from a third party's FTP server, unzips the files and copies them to a blob storage container.

The throughput is incredibly low (7 KB/s) and simply copying the files without unzipping does not pose any issue (700 KB/s which is in line with regular download speed from this FTP server using FileZilla for example).

For the Data Factory team the run id is : 825e15a9-aba6-47ed-8656-88c9b6bc3754

Some names in the following datasets have been modified.

Input dataset :

`{
    "name": "InputDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "3PPFtpServer",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "FileShare",
        "typeProperties": {
            "compression": {
                "type": "ZipDeflate",
                "level": "Fastest"
            },
            "fileName": "sample_file.zip",
            "folderPath": "/dir1/dir2/"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}`

Output dataset :

`{
    "name": "OutputDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "",
            "folderPath": "test-output/"
        }
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}`

Am I getting something wrong regarding tuning my decompression ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the ftp server with a self-hosted integration runtime? Or is it an Azure IR?

If it is self-hosted, chances are that your processing power is not enough to unzip and upload the file faster, so the best plan for this is to upload the zipped file, and then decompress it in the Azure Storage, so that it unzips the file in the cloud. You will have 2 copy activities and 3 datasets:

Activity 1: copy compressed file from ftp to Azure Storage. Datasets will be as you have now but the output dataset will use the same type of compression as the input.
Activity 2: copy decompressed file from Azure Storage to Azure Storage (another folder of course). The input dataset will be the same as Activity1's output, and the output will be the dataset that you are showing in your question.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I am using the Azure IR but I will try using 2 activities.

Comment: I am also facing low throughput when using ZipDeflate. I decompress files on the cloud (something similar as Marting said) and it takes more than 3h to decompress 900MB zipped file. 
@Martin Esteban Zurita
I develop some other pipelines that need to decompress .gz file (using gz compression type) and it performed much much faster. I think there is also an impact of which algorithm they used to compress files. That is something we can't boost with ADF.